# flexslider 2 continues loop in one direction not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am trying to make flexslider to loop in one direction contineously in one direction. ones it reachs the last image in the loop then it should start from the first image again.

I have two issue with the example i have set up on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ySY5x/2/)

One: I am not able to make it work on jsFiddle

Two: animation is on at the end it then start in the other direction while i want to to move in one direction only Left to Right.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    easing: "linear",
    useCSS: false,
    randomize: false,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    slideshowSpeed: 12,
    animationSpeed: 8000,
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

### First issue

You miss a closing `)};` at the end of the script so it is not valid, and you have to set the script section as `No wrap - in <head>` in the Framework and extension panel.

For the first image you left the full path `http://flexslider.woothemes.com/`

### Second issue

The only loop feature can be set using `animationLoop: true` for now is the only solution.

Here a request pulled in github for a more smooth animation and loop: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/287

Code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: true,
        easing: "linear",
        useCSS: false,
        randomize: false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 12,
        animationSpeed: 8000,
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: false,
        itemWidth: 210,
        itemMargin: 5,
        start: function (slider) {
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
    });
});
```

Docs: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6TXzC/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't run in loop as i had requested

Comment: Take a look at the second issue section and at the related github request

Comment: I had a problem before that 'animationLoop:true' doesn't take effect, however, I finally removed 'itemWidth:blah', then it works. Strange, isn't it?